# Self-Sorted Data Structure with Key Lookup/Merge

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, key

I am looking for a value-sorted data structure in Java that supports key lookup/merging(Note: the key and the value are seperated properties)

My past experiences were:

- TreeMap with a custom CompareByValueComparator, which yielded a bugged map that did not match the keys correctly and I could never figure out why.
- TreeSet with Map.Entry elements, which does not support keys searching and I have to search element by element to find that key, which takes O(n) time and is not really efficient.
- HashMap and TreeSet combination, which is very slow when transfering elements from one structure to the other, or bulky if you want to maintain both.

Thanks

EDIT1: fix the wording about "casting" in the third options.

Comment: A HashMap plus TreeSet should work. What do you mean by "casting elements from one structure to the other"? You shouldn't need to do casting, and that also generally takes negligible time in Java.

Comment: First option seems great, and should work , if "never figure out' maybe there is something missing but it should

Comment: @azro If you're sorting by value, it's not going to allow for lookup by key.

Comment: Why do you need value-sort ?

Comment: What is key merging? Do you mean the data structure has a merge function that can be used to combine with another type of the same data structure, in effect merging the keys and values into one bigger structure (of same type)?

Comment: @ThisClark key merging means that I can combine values of the same key with some merge functions, similar to Java Map.merge, in a sense I just need some ways to look up keys in the structure

Comment: @azro I agree with Dukeling, I suspected that because of sorting by values, the TreeMap mismatched the keys

Comment: @Dukeling you sure about negligible time? I used addAll or putAll to transfer data from one structure to the other, and the running time was significantly longer, like 2 or 3 times more than the bugged TreeMap. Maybe "casting" is not the right word

Comment: @QuynhVo Yes, "casting" has a very specific meaning in Java, which is not that. If you're constantly copying a bunch of elements between the two, that's going to be slow. You should only be modifying, adding or removing the element(s) you want to change, and nothing else. If you only change one or two elements, you shouldn't use addAll.

Comment: @QuynhVo If it's 2-3 times slower than using a TreeMap efficiently, that's still not much and would be about expected, since you have 2 structures instead of 1. If it gets much slower as your input size increases, that would be a problem. But it's hard to be sure what exactly you're doing, or whether it's as efficient as one would expect, based on your description.

Comment: A bidirectional map can look up values by keys or keys by values, but then you can't have duplicate values as that would overwrite the corresponding key for that value. This data structure is sorted by value and by key but it is mapped for lookup and replacement by either. The point of key lookup is quick access to values by key. Sorting the values makes me wonder why you don't just use a List of objects that have keys on them, write methods to sort by keys or by values and binary search to find either one you need after sorting. Sort anything = O(n log n) + search = O(log n).